# Search DB with data in XML, in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I have an XML like:

```
<Users><User LoginName="XYZ" /><User LoginName="ABC" /> ... </Users>
```

I have a DB table [UserData] in Oracle having LoginName.

I need to write a query that I'll execute from code (VB.NET) and I need to get all the rows where LoginName is same as mentioned in the XML.

Please note - I can not Parse the XML in the code and call the select statement with IN keyword.

I am having similar SQL Server query for the same.

```
DECLARE @Users XML

SET @UsersOutOfCSV = '<Users><User LoginName="XYZ" /><User LoginName="ABC" /></Users>'

SELECT UserData.* from UserData,@Users.nodes('/Users /User ') Users (node)
WHERE UserData.LoginName = Users.Node.value('@LoginName', 'VARCHAR(50)')
```

I basically needs to convert this above SQL server query to Oracle.

Thanks in Advance for help.

Comment: I have to use Oracle 11gR2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent is:

```
select u.*
from xmltable('/Users/User'
  passing xmltype('<Users><User LoginName="XYZ" /><User LoginName="ABC" /></Users>')
  columns loginname varchar2(50) path '@LoginName') x
join userdata u on u.loginname = x.loginname;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e966d/1).

The [`xmltype()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/t_xml.htm) generates an XML object from your string; exactly where you're getting it from might change how you want to generate that (if it's stored in a table already, for example), and you're limited on the overall length if it is just a string. I imagine you'll be passing the string value as a bind variable.

The [`xmltable()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm) then converts that into multiple pseudo-rows, one for each `User` element under `Users`. The `columns` part of that seems to be similar to your SQL Server node extraction - same `@LoginName` construction to get an attribute. (I guess that's standard, come to think of it).

Finally that generated table is joined to your `UserData` table as normal.

Comment: I got stuck up into one more problem, the same query as you gave above. I have XML text that is more than 4000 characters, now I tried to pass the XML text as parameter also from code but still the same error as this is the max what oracle support.

Do you have any quick solution to that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @user3137079 - you'll need to pass the parameter as a `clob`; [there's an `xmltype` constructor that accepts that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71992). How you pass it depends on your client and driver, and how that handles bind variables. If you can't figure that aspect out you should ask a new question and include your current calling code.